# Python print return null

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, loops, variables, boto3

when i execute this code it return None, but i want to print the integer like in the loop, anyone know why please ?

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('autoscaling')
clearesponse = client.describe_auto_scaling_groups(
    AutoScalingGroupNames=[
        'XXXX',
    ])


for reservation in clearesponse ['AutoScalingGroups']:
        test=print(reservation['DesiredCapacity'])


nb_desired_cap = test
print (nb_desired_cap)
print (test)
```

Run :

python describe_instances.py

4

None

None

run the code and want to catch the result 4 in other variable for use in other part of the code

Comment: Working as intended. `print` does not and should not return anything.

Comment: `test=print(reservation['DesiredCapacity'])` makes no sense. either just print inside the loop or append the results into a list to be printed later

Answer (score 7):

It's because the `print` function returns `None`. In the example below, "Hello, World!" is not returned, but just printed to the screen, and what is returned is `None`.

```
>>> result = print("Hello, World!")
Hello, World!
>>> result is None
True
```

You can contrast this with a function that does not print anything, just returns the input. If you used it in a script, it would not print anything on the screen. In REPL it's not that self-evident, but with strings, you can notice the quotes.

```
>>> def identity(x):
...     return x
... 
>>> result = identity("Hello, World!")
>>> result == "Hello, World!"
True
```

Finally, you can do both:

```
>>> def myprint(string):
...     print(string)
...     return string
... 
>>> myprint("Hello, World!")
Hello, World!
'Hello, World!'
```

If you run the function above in REPL, it would show the input two times, from a script it would show it only once (the printed value).

I'm not sure what you want your code to do, but you probably would like to assign to the variable something else than the result returned by `print`.